# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Attachment>'

Tags: flutter, email-attachments, mailer, dynamic-list

I use the [flutter form builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder) to get image with camera/gallery and then I want to attach them to an email(I use [mailer](https://pub.dev/packages/mailer) for this) but when I try to send the email I get the following error:

`type 'List< dynamic >' is not a subtype of type 'List< Attachment >'`

[image]
Is there I way to convert the dynamic list to attachment list?

this is my code:

I get the images using the FormBuilderImagePicker widget :

```
FormBuilderImagePicker(
 attribute: 'image',
 onChanged: (value) {
  _attachments.add(value);
  debugPrint('attachments: $_attachments');
},
maxImages: 3,
defaultImage:
AssetImage('assets/images/icons8-plus-64.png'),
validators: [
 FormBuilderValidators.required(),
],
),
```

and this is my code for sending emails:

```
  void sendEmailWithoutPosition(
  String name,
  String destination,
  String subject,
  String description,
  String email,
  String number,
  List<Attachment> attachments,
  BuildContext context) async {
message = Message()
  ..from = Address(username, name)
  ..recipients.add(destination)
  ..subject = ' Petiție ${subject.toString()} - aplicația e-Rădăuți'
  ..html = 'Către, ${destination.toString()} <br><br> Stimată doamnă/ Stimate domn,'
      '<br><br>Subsemnatul ${name.toString()}, vă supun atenției următoarea problemă:<br><br>'
      '$description<br><br>În conformitate cu atribuțiile pe care le aveți, vă rog să luați'
      ' măsurile ce se impun.<br><br>'
      'Prezenta sesizare reprezintă o petiție în sensul O.G. nr. 27/2002 privind activitatea de soluționare a petițiilor și '
      'a fost transmisă prin intermediul aplicației mobile e-Rădăuți, dezvoltată'
      ' de Ascociația Rădăuțiul Civic, prin funcționalitatea „Sesizează o problemă”.<br><br>'
      'Vă rog să îmi transmiteți răspunsul în termenul legal la adresa $email'
      '.<br><br>Cu stimă,<br><br>'
      '     $name<br><br>     Tel: $number/$email'
  ..attachments.addAll(attachments);
tryToSendEmail(message);
}

Future<bool> tryToSendEmail(var message) async {
final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);
try {
  final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
  debugPrint('Message sent: ' + sendReport.toString());
} on MailerException catch (e) {
  print('Message not sent.');
  for (var p in e.problems) {
    print('Problem: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
  }
}
}
```

I've tried to map the list using this code:

```
List<Attachment> listAttachments = _attachments
                            .map((e) => e as Attachment)
                            .toList();
                        List<Attachment> listAttachmentsNew =
                            listAttachments.cast<Attachment>();
```

but now I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: It's difficult to understand the problem just by looking at the stacktrace. Can you give us some code to understand better the scope of your question?

Comment: oh well most of my code is from the docs from the 2 packages but sure I'll post the code

Comment: I think the most relevant part is when you do List<dynamic> something = somethingElse. This to understand what "somethingElse" is and to see if it's possible to map the content of that list to a list of attachments

Comment: @AndreaCostanzo1 I've added how I tried to map the list and the error that I get

Comment: You can't simply cast since attachment is an abstract class. You have to properly create attachments using a constructor. I posted an answer below to give you a better view of how you should handle this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By diving deeper into the structure of the package what I suggest you is to use a constructor: attachment is an abstract class and it can't be simply casted. Depending on the type of attachment you can do:

```
//FOR FILE ATTACHMENTS
List<Attachment> listAttachments = _attachments.map((e) => FileAttachment(e.file)).toList();
//FOR STRING ATTACHMENTS
List<Attachment> listAttachments = _attachments.map((e) => StringAttachment(e.data)).toList();
```

Obviously adapt the code to your data.
To have a better idea of how these class are structured give a look at this page: [Attachment class github reference](https://github.com/kaisellgren/mailer/blob/master/lib/src/entities/attachment.dart)

**Update:** I gave a look into the library you are using but it lacks documentation. Insted of using **onChanged** try using **onImage**. In this way, every time you pick an image you should get the data you need.

Comment: it says: Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_File' has no instance getter 'file'.

Comment: Ok luis, if "e" is already a file you have to do (e) => FileAttachment(e). If you give me more information about to what class "e" belongs I can update the code above to make it work for your specific case

Comment: if I put simply just "e" i get the same error: Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Attachment>'
Mailer wants a FileAttachment but  the FormBuilderImagePicker returns a List<dynamic> and somehow I have to convert the returned list from ImagePicker to attachment type.. oh btw FormBuiler uses https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker" to get the images

Comment: Luis, the class of the package you are using lacks documentation. I tried to look at the code but sometimes it becomes confusing. It has an onImage method but it doesn't appear to be called. Try to use that method, otherwise open a issue on their github page asking explanation for that specific class since from the documentation it isn't clear.

Comment: okay thank you but I've done something like this File file1 = FileAttachments(attachments[1]); and listAttachments = [file1]; for the 3 pictures I know it's not somethign good but yeah it works now
PS attachments is of tyoe List<dynamic> and listAttachments is of type List<Attachments>

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass the `List<dynamic>` attachments instead of `List<Attachment>`. try that.

Comment: I tried this before posting this question but thanks